# Validate Date from another object

Tags: validation, date

I want to create validation rule on Object 1 to check date on another custom object Object 2. The Object 1 has a look-up field to Object 2. I want to compare create date of record of Object 1 and custom date field of Object 2.
I try validation rule on Object 1 but can't make it work. Here is what I tried:

```
 $ObjectType.SCMC__Purchase_Order__c.Fields.SCMC__End_Date__c <  CreatedDate
```

And I get this error message:

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '<'. Expected Object, received DateTime

Is this kind of validation possible through validation rule?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the standard Salesforce UI to build your validation rule, you should be able to use a cross object formula to access the related object (Object 2).

This should look something like:

```
SCMC__Purchase_Order__r.SCMC__End_Date__c < CreatedDate
```

If you were using standard objects, say from Opportunity to Account, it'd look like this:

```
Account.CreatedDate < CreatedDate
```

Comment: Thanks, but still the same error:  Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '<'. Expected Date, received DateTime. Should I use something like DATEVALUE? I tried but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the custom field, which is of type date and CreatedDate being Datetime, you need to modify your formula a bit to make it as:

```
SCMC__Purchase_Order__r.SCMC__End_Date__c < DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)
```

DATEVALUE returns the date part of CreatedDate, enabling you to compare the two fields.

Hope this helps!